# Create a blank class instance without class definition

Tags: python, oop

Sometimes I use classes without any structure, i.e.

```
class Foo(object):
    pass

foo = Foo()
```

I wonder if there is a more compact way which avoids the clumsy, meaningless definition. Can one directly initialize blank object-instances?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`type()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type):

```
>>> foo = type('Foo', (), {})()
>>> foo
<__main__.Foo object at 0x100499f50>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
foo = object()
```

is the common way.

Comment: I was sure as death to have checked that, but obviously I haven't. Thanks!

Comment: Note that you won't be able to add any attributes to `object` instances, like `foo` in this example. If you just need a unique object (for instance, as a sentinel value), this is a good way to go, but if you need to be able to store data in the object it won't work.

Comment: `foo1=object()` and `foo2=Foo()` behave different, even though the `Foo` class got no additional ingredients. Is there a deeper reason for this strange behavior? Is object really a class or something spooky nonstandard?

Comment: @flonk `object` is a built-in class.